# next page data not loading with react infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-query

can you please check out this project?
I have a feed page
and some posts like 1000
and is limited to 10 per page
I'm using react infinite scroll and react query
to load more posts when the user scrolls at the near of the last post
but it won't work
I don't know if the problem is the API endpoint or what
because when I use Jason placeholder API It's fine
but when I use mine it's not
ill appreciate it if u check it out

sandbox project: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-glitter-bt3pb0?file=/src/index.tsx

my own API mock: https://uniplato.staging.uniplato.us/api/v1/mock-data

the expected behavior is that it should load the posts of the next page when scrolled to the bottom
the actual behaviour is not doing this
there isn't any error as I think its a logical problem

I attempted changing the API endpoint and the map function arrays
the API endpoint changing worked ( i also had the change the map function i.e it wasn't pg.data.data.data
it was pg.map
but for my own API, I should've done it like pg.data.data.data
after all
the jasonplaceholder worked
but mine didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you refer to the sandbox, I did some changes there and I used the mockup function. The issue was with the getNextPageParam most likely.

[Code Sand Box Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wright-sio7yo)

Comment: this worked! 
I was completely stuck on this one for the entire day and just didn't know what to do just copied and pasted it from videos  
I don't know if it's the right place to ask 
but how did you learn this level of JS? how much time and effort you've put into it?

Comment: the one you shared worked, 
but there's a tiny issue 
when the next page of data loads the previous ones disappear 
it looks like the new ones replace the previous ones, why?

Comment: ok i realized its loading the previous page its just HTML / CSS issue

Comment: I'm happy that I helped! Sorry for the late response, glad that you figured the rest out.